# JSONP Ajax calls not working parallel

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, node.js, browserify

I have Node.js server and jQuery ajax requests.

This works:

```
api(config.categoriesURL, success, config.err1);
setTimeout(function () {
    api(config.randomURL, success1, config.err2);
},300);
```

But this doesn't:

```
api(config.categoriesURL, success, config.err1);
api(config.randomURL, success1, config.err2);
```

Here is the console output:

> ```
> url: http://localhost:3000/categories/?callback=myCallback&_=1431726147454
> url: http://localhost:3000/random/?callback=myCallback&category=55564cc42e366b34aa9a529d&callback=myCallback&_=1431726147455
> responseText: undefined
> status: 200
> text status: parsererror
> error: Error: myCallback was not called'
> ```

Is this server-side or client-side problem? Any idea why this is happening and how I should solve it? Is this normal behaviour?

Here is more code:

**main.js**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var api = require('./api'),
    config = require('./config');

    function success (data) {
        data.forEach(function (category) {
            var div = document.createElement('div');
            div.id = category._id;
            div.textContent = category.name;
            $('.container').append(div);
        });
    }

    function success2 (data) {
        console.log(data);
    }

    api(config.categoriesURL, success, config.err1);
    api(config.randomURL, success2, config.err2);


});
```

**api.js**

```
function api(url, success, error) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: url,
        beforeSend: function (jqXHR, settings) {
            console.log('url: ' + settings.url);
        },
        jsonpCallback: 'myCallback',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        success: success,
        error: error
    });
}

module.exports = api;
```

Comment: A bit more code would be useful, some stuff before you call those functions.

Comment: @Sidd, I updated more code. Please let me know if you need more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try removing:

```
jsonpCallback: 'myCallback',
```

You are making two simultaneous JSONP ajax calls that use the same name for the callback function. I would think that would be a problem.

If you remove the `jsonpCallback` setting, jQuery will randomly generate the name of the callback function.

Comment: Cool! Now the first api call works but the second one gives the same parsererror and it says `jQuery21404176367884501815_1431730654390 was not called`

Comment: I got it. I had `myCallback` hardcoded to the second url. Thanks!